# How to add my own image with message like emoticons

Tags: iphone, ios, emoticons

okay...

I have asked this question about this but there is a new thing that i want to ask..

like emoticons I want to add my own image  with the iphone message ...

I am thankful if anybody can give me the idea about how to do this???

is this possible??

Comment: when you say iPhone message, do you mean SMS message or E-mail message?

Comment: Yup...my mistake....wrong link..i am taking it off..its for mail and I want to use custom emoticons like my image in iphone messages...any possibility??

Comment: That link you posted is for app that does smiley for twitter and e-mail.  If you create your own e-mail messaging app, you can add your own images.

Comment: This question doesn't even begin to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control the behavior of the Mail application. You cannot achieve this behavior unless you are providing your own email entry form.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer...Can u pls elaborate??

Comment: Because you don't have access to the Mail app and it's core functionality, you can't insert your images like you want. If you wrote an app that the user entered their message with, your would be able to replace text emoticons (' =) ', ' ^_^ ', etc.) with images from your own application before sending that to the Mail application.

Comment: So...like you said in the last part of your answer...if I try to send any image...at the other end ...it will be replaced by some kind of emoticons...am is understanding right??

Comment: No. Your application needs to do that on the senders side, before the message is sent.

Comment: So...We can say as the final verdict that we can not customize emoticons...i.e. we can not send our custom image with that...Right??

Comment: That's correct, *unless* you provide your own custom email creation form within your own application.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the message you need to decode the characters and display corresponding image for that character.
For example if you receive message :-) it is ':','-' and ')' then display an smiley image... similarly different emotions for different messages.
 You need to maintain the list of character set and corresponding image for that set of characters